# What is the difference between `now` and `block.timestamp`?

Tags: solidity, transactions

My main goal is to obtain time spent between two transaction calls inside my smart-contract. I am not sure, should I depend on `now` or `block.timestamp` to obtain the most accurate time difference in between transactions.

I have call my contract's start() and end() functions to store `now` and/or `block.timestamp` values. `getTimeDif()` returns the difference.

**Contract-1:**

```
contract Now {
   uint start;
   uint end;
   function start(){
      start = now;
   } 
   function end(){
      end = now;
   } 
   function getTimeDif() returns(uint){
      return end - start;
   }     
}
```

**Scnerio:**

```
Now.start(); //Transaction mined on blk.num=100.
Now.end();  //Transaction mined on blk.num=200.
console.log( Timestamp. getTimeDif(); )  //Transaction called on blk.num=201.
```

---

**Contract-2:**

```
contract Timestamp {
   uint start;
   uint end;
   function start(){
      start = block.timestamp;
   } 
   function end(){
      end = block.timestamp;
   } 
   function getTimeDif() returns(uint){
      return end - start;
   }     
}
```

**Scnerio:**

```
Timestamp.start(); //Transaction mined on blk.num=100.
Timestamp.end();  //Transaction mined on blk.num=200.
console.log( Timestamp. getTimeDif(); )  //Transaction called on blk.num=201.
```

**[Q]**  On the contracts above, should I assume difference between stored `now` value and stored `block.stamp` value to be same? `( Timestamp.getTimeDif() ?= Now.getTimeDif() )` Which one might return me the most accurate time difference between two called transactions?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

> What is the difference between `now` and `block.timestamp`?

Nothing. They're aliases. From the [documentation](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/units-and-global-variables.html?highlight=block.timestamp#block-and-transaction-properties):

```
now (uint): current block timestamp (alias for block.timestamp)
```

---

**Update:** (Thanks @ShaneFontaine)

Solidity [0.7.0](https://github.com/ethereum/solidity/releases/tag/v0.7.0) deprecated the `now` keyword.

For contracts ^0.7.0, you must use `block.timestamp`.

Comment: Update: Solidity 0.7.0 deprecated the `now` keyword. For contracts ^0.7.0, you must use `block.timestamp`.

Comment: Thanks for the update! Do you mind if I update my answer (referencing your comment)? :-)

Comment: Not at all. Please feel free to update it.

Answer (score 0):

Use `block.timestamp` instead of `now`.

This is still true for Solidity - 0.8.11. Using Truffle v5.4.32 and VSCode which is where I got the **TypeError**.