# now keyword in Solidity

Tags: solidity

I was unable to find any relevant documentation for the `now` keyword within the [Solidity documentation](http://solidity.readthedocs.io/), other than its usage in examples. What exactly does the `now` keyword return, how is it determined and what are the associated gas costs? I assume it is similar to Unix time.

Comment: Related: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/15747/what-is-the-difference-between-now-and-block-timestamp/15748#15748

Answer (score 22, accepted):

In short `now` is just an alias for `block.timestamp` and it is the number of seconds since the Epoch as per [documentation](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/latest/units-and-global-variables.html?highlight=block#block-and-transaction-properties).

Beware that this value is set by miners so there is a little potential for a malicious manipulation but general nodes are [meant to coordinate](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/5924/how-do-ethereum-mining-nodes-maintain-a-time-consistent-with-the-network/5931#5931).

**EDIT (17 Jan 2024):**
`now` has been [deprecated](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.23/units-and-global-variables.html#:%7E:text=In%20version%200.7.0%2C%20the%20alias%20now%20(for%20block.timestamp)%20was%20removed) post version 0.7.0.

> **Note:** In version 0.7.0, the alias now (for block.timestamp) was removed.

Comment: Update: Solidity 0.7.0 deprecated the `now` keyword. For contracts ^0.7.0, you must use `block.timestamp`.

Comment: It's worth noting that miners can manipulate block.timestamp & the old 'now' keyword. You can't rely on timestamp, previous block number hash, difficulty, etc because miners can exploit this to call your function with parameters that result in them winning / knowing random number outcome.